# 1009 Type error in FF12 only

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, actionscript

At my wits end with this now, Firefox in its never-ending wisdom *cough* seems to have knackered flash in its later version (I'm running 12) and an app that works in every single other version of Firefox, and every version of every other browser (yeah, including IE!)

So when running my app (its more of a polyfill for functionality not supported) it falls over on the call to a Matrix translate. It never used to do this and I have reason to think its a Firefox bug (dumping out the Matrix object gives me an empty object?)

I have put the code below that causes the error

```
try {
    var smx:Matrix = new Matrix;
    smx.translate(-100, -50);
} catch (e:*) {
    ExternalInterface.call('console.log', e);
}
```

Any help would be magical, like a unicorn but to make the shambles that Firefox has become play ball.

Comment: It would be most interesting to know what version of Flash you are deploying to, and what your current plugin version is...

Comment: a shambles it is indeed!! What line does the error occur on? and what is the full text of the error? These are helpful things when it comes to debugging code, you know.

Comment: The error occurs on the translate because the Matrix object is empty? Totally stupid, they broke their sanitize.js as well so it crashes all the time. The version of Flash I am deploying to is 10 and 10.1 and the plugin version is "11.2.202.235"

Comment: The exact same code works fine on FF12 and with the same export setting and plugin version for me...  Is there any chance something else might be wrong?  What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm just stripping bits out of it to narrow down the issue. Will report back.

Comment: It is actually BitmapData which is undefined in Firefox?

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried including the brackets when you instantiate your Matrix object? eg. var smx:Matrix = new Matrix();

Comment: You'll have to edit your question and post some more code - `BitmapData` is not undefined, *a* BitmapData variable is. My guess is, there's some load operation, or otherwise timing critical task that's the culprit.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet yeah I tried everything like that and weltraumpirat I managed to work it out, for some reason BitMapData wasn't instantiating properly and was causing the error but didn't throw an error to explain why it wasn't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it was an issue with BitmapData not instantiating properly and throwing a type error in the end. Always parenthesize!

Avoid:

```
var someVar = new BitmapData;
```

and use:

```
var someVar = new BitmapData();
```

Which is every annoying since I hate duplicate code.